# SPARK RDD Partition on a single HDFS Split

Tags: apache-spark

If we have a file of 128MB with an HDFS split of 128MB and we issue sc.textFile(xxx,4), what actually happens? What does the RDD in fact mean in this case in terms of partitioning? 4 processing partitions still or just 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a code like this:

```
JavaRDD<String> in = sc.textFile(xxx,4);
in.persist();
```

Then your RDD has 4 Partitions. They should have a size of 32 MB each. Then you can do something likes this:

```
rdd.count()
```

When you run then your code locally with local[4], then the count will be executed with 4 processes (tasks) in parallel.

Comment: OK, but the text states by default it will be HDFS blocksize, so this is not true. With you still. Then, if not using local[4] what then? The partitions will all be in memory on same node as 4 parts or just 1 part with pointers to start, end etc.? MR seems a little easier to follow. @Simon Schiff